# Windows Server 2008 Troubleshooting: Server falling over on a timely basis

Tags: windows-server-2008, troubleshooting

All,

This is a generic question, and I know it will upset some people, for which I apologise.

I have recently taken a new role, and part of that role involves some sysadmin for Windows 2008 Servers (R2). One of these servers that I have to look at is failing regularly on a weekly basis (within the small time-frame on the same day).

I started by looking for events, and the only ones that appears are relating to Group Policy (that occur  regularly around this time). I have also looked for scheduled tasks and tasks relating to the main application (I can't see any issues in the logs/config for this application either), however, there is nothing that is within/near this period.

I was just wondering if there was anything obvious I am missing. I have a very little in the way of sysadmin experience (it has always been a by-product of my roles), but am moving more into this area, so any t'shooting tips would be welcome!

Any thoughts and advice will extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by giving us more detail. Stating that "One of these servers that I have to look at is failing regularly" doesn't tell us anything about the nature of the problem. How is it failing? Is it crashing, rebooting, shutting down, etc? What is the "main" application on this server that you made reference to?

Comment: Please see the tips [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) and see if you can flesh out this question into something answerable. Log files and detailed troubleshooting on your part will help you get an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is something obvious you are missing. Since it appears to be failing at a regular time you should set up a fine detailed Performance Monitor capture to figure out exactly what is happening to your system (and from which process).

[How to configure Perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115.aspx)

That being said, you really should better define what "failing" means.